# Batch parse devcon.exe

Tags: batch-file

Currently I have script which work perfect on Windows 7, using pnputil. This Script looking for specific Drivers, and remove it.

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('%windir%\Sysnative\pnputil -e') do for /F "tokens=*" %%b in ("%%a") do (
   if "%%b" equ "FTDI" (
      echo Removing..... !line1prior!
      %windir%\Sysnative\pnputil -f -d !line1prior!
   ) else (
      set "line1prior=%%b"
   )
)
```

Now I would like to add support for Win XP, so DevCon works perfect. But I have still problem to parse  output of devcon.exe ... output is different.

For PnPutul each line is delimited with "*:*", on "*devcon.exe dp_enum*" looks different...
can some one help me?

I used devcon.exe from here: http://www.cammckenzie.com/blog/index.php/2012/06/25/download-devcon-for-windows-7/

Comment: What does the output of devcon look like and how does it need to be parsed? Please consider updating your question to include this information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]:" %%a in ('devcon dp_enum^|Find /n "FTDI"') do (
  set /a "line1prior=%%a-2"
  for /f "tokens=1 delims=*" %%b in ('devcon dp_enum^|more +!line1prior!') do (
    echo devcon -f dp_delete %%b & goto :out
  )
)
:out
```

Remove the echo if the output looks right to do the actual delete.